# Files downloading process automate with selenium

Tags: file, selenium-webdriver, download

URLs are in the file, need to copy from this file and hit in the browser. This process need to be done for all the URLs one by one. File size is less than 1 MB in max conditions. After downloading completes then only another file downloading will start, that means at any time active download is 1.

This process i am doing manually, for downloading of 125 files. This number may increase in coming days. So I am planing to automate this process. Can i achieve this in selenium?

I have knowledge on selenium webdriver, i can able to write the simple scripts. 
If it is not possible with selenium, refer the any alternate ways.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, read the excel file using Selenium/Java. Refer below link for more information:

https://www.guru99.com/all-about-excel-in-selenium-poi-jxl.html

Read url from excel sheet one after the other:

```
while(current_row<=row_count)
{
driver.get("url captured from the excel")
}
```

I assume that file gets downloaded automatically when you hit the url. In case of any specific element to be displayed after download is done, you can waitUntilElementVisible or Sikuli can be used for downloading ( In case of manual download)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to rad from excel sheet

```
public class excel {

    public static String getExcelData(String sheetName, int rowNum,int colNum)
    {
        String url=null;
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("filepath.xls");
            Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            Sheet s=wb.getSheet(sheetName);
            Row r=s.getRow(rowNum);
            Cell c=r.getCell(colNum);
            retval=c.getStringCellValue();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return url;

    }
}
```

- Code will return you the url
- use this url for downloading the file
- `WebDriver driver;`
- `driver.get(url);`

This will down load the file.